# how to identify duplicate integers within a list, than minus each integer following the duplicate by one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve an issue that I am currently running into. I want to have to have a list that is made up of only random integers. Then if i find a duplicate integer within this list i want to minus the rest of the list by one, after the second time the duplicate number appeared. Furthermore if a second pair of duplicate numbers are encountered, it should then minus the rest of the list by two, than if a third by three and etc.

But it should not affect the same duplicate number or any other duplicated number (that differs from the first) that is in the sequence.

For example

```
mylist = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 8 5 10 11 12 1 14 15 16 17]
```

I want the end result to look like;

```
mylist = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 7 5 9 10 11 1 12 13 14 15]
```

I have some rough code that I created to attempt this, but it will always minus the whole list including duplicated integers (the first pairs and any further pairs).

If someone can shed some light on how to deal with this problem i will be highly grateful!

Sorry forgot to add my code

```
a = [49, 51, 53, 56, 49, 54, 53, 48]
dupes = list()
number = 1
print (dupes)
while True:
#move integers from a to dupes (one by one)
    for i in a[:]:
        if i >= 2:
            dupes.append(i)
            a.remove(i)
            if dupes in a:
                a = [x - number for x in a]
            print (dupes)
            print(dupes)
    if dupes in a:
        a = [x - number for x in a]
        number = number+1
break
```

Forgot to mention earlier, me and friend are currently working on this problem and the code i supplied is our rough outline of what is should look like and now the end result, I know that it does now work so i decided to ask for help for the issue

Comment: Even if you code doesn't work, provide it. We will start from it / correct your mistakes

Comment: Your example does not adhere to the function you want to write.

Comment: Keep a set of found items. Keep a duplicates count. Now, go through your list one item at a time, generating a new list. Optionally you can set mylist = newlist at the end, but I would just return the new list.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a simaler problem.

Comment: Sorry just added it, if it does not look right, it is because it is not meant to!.it is a rough outline of i what i think it might look like and function

Comment: Can you address the problem of the "expected" value not matching the problem description? You handle the 2 and 1 dups, but ignore the 5 dup.

Comment: What is the correct output for the input [1, 1, 1, 1, 10]?

Comment: I have just realised that i made a crucial error in explaining my problem, the inputted numbers are not meant to be random (that was my bad when i was looking over notes) each number in the original list represents a position, so number 0 represents the first place that something can be. so with your question of the output [1, 1, 1, 1, 10] will never be possible with the rest of my code, an input that has a similar format will look like [0, 0, 0, 0, 4] but i want the outcome to be [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Comment: That's okay; it doesn't matter to this function. The important point was do we subtract for duplicate duplicates, which you have now answered, thank you. You still need to fix the incorrect example in the question. I think the answer should have been [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 10, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through your list and when you encounter a duplicate(can use list slicing) then decrement the next item!

List slicing - example,

```
>>> L=[2,4,6,8,10] 
>>> L[1:5] # all elements from index 1 to 5
[4, 6, 8, 10] 
>>> L[3:] # all elements from index 3 till the end of list
[8, 10]
>>> L[:2] # all elements from index beginning of list to second element
[2, 4]
>>> L[:-2] # all elements from index beginning of list to last second element
[2, 4, 6]
>>> L[::-1] # reverse the list
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

And [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)

> returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0)
>   and the values obtained from iterating over sequence

Therefore,

```
mylist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 5, 10, 11, 12, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17]
dup=0
for index,i in enumerate(mylist):
    if i in mylist[:index]:
        dup+=1
    else:
        mylist[index]-=dup
print mylist
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 5, 8, 9, 10, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: O(n**2) for what should be O(n) problem.  Answer doesn't meet spec: The subtrahend is the number of duplicates found. I would point out that the OP provided an expected answer, but ... it doesn't match the spec either. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! It does seem to work for the first duplicated pair (the integer 8 has become 7 as shown in your example) but it the rest of the numbers are unaffected. For example the number 9 should have been 8 and 11 should have been 9. I am not sure on how to alter your code to do so though ;(

Comment: I've edited my answer!  And also, as pointed by @KennyOstrom thee expected output as per your question doesnt seem to match what you have explained there.

Comment: You are getting what I believe to be the correct answer now. I am concerned about the performance on larger inputs. If you use a set, the average performance should be O(n). I guess the theoretical worst case must always be O(n**2) but you don't want that to be the norm. Additionally, I would prefer it return a new list instead of modifying the input in-place, but that's just my opinion on good practice.

Comment: Hi thanks you for your new suggestion! It is perfect for what i need. Thanks soo much. I don't think i should be worried about the performance of this code as it is for my compression code for text files, and i dont think i will need it to be fast. As long as it can handle around 10 integers. Also it didnt have to be in a the same list, but it does benefit me as my code is getting quite long winded and having less variable, list and etc makes my head hurt a whole lot less xD

Comment: It will not have a problem with about 10 integers. :)